# sub-menu items of Drop-down menu with carousal in bootstrap is not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a requirement to show drop-down menus in a bootstrap carousal. Everything is working except the sub-menu items(hide behind the content).

`JSFiddle:`

https://jsfiddle.net/Saneesh/pwmyvsw6/65/

How can I fix this issue?

`EDIT`

the solution https://jsfiddle.net/pwmyvsw6/67/ works, but the horizontal scrollbar is appearing when we `click on the previous and next button` like in the screenshot below. how can we hide the scrollbar in this solution?

[image]

`THE IDEA I GOT IS` instead of menu use tabs. it will be possible to achieve the scroll-able tabs and tab content show as menu items.

Answer (score 2):

After checking your fiddle it would seem that the carousel class has some styles that are stopping your dropdown from displaying. Adding the below to your stylesheet will display them.

```
#myCarousel .carousel-inner {
  overflow:visible;
}
```

It is currently set to `overflow:hidden;` which is causing the dropdown not to display.

I have used the ID of the carousel to target the class so that it doesn't cause problems in the future; just in case you add another carousel and it behaves differently. As I think `overflow:hidden;` might be a default style, but it can be easily over-ridden.

Here is a link to the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pwmyvsw6/66/

Comment: Hi sweetheart, your code works great but I've refactored it and changed the `z-index` property, so the dropdown bars doesn't collide with menu bars anymore. https://jsfiddle.net/pwmyvsw6/67/

Comment: Thank you very much @Neelam and @Daniek! In your solutions I can see one issue the horizontal scrollbar is visible when the menu items move.

Comment: No worries @San, when does the horizontal scrollbar appear? At what screen size (breakpoint) so I can help you because it seems fine in the fiddle.

Comment: Hello @NeelamKhan, it we can see in the fiddle as well. Click on the left or right arrow and observe the bottom of that area, you can see the scrollbar. it appears and disappear.